# Regex for numbers between 0 and 180 and decimals places in Javacc

Tags: java, regex, javacc

So I'm creating a token in JavaCC by using regex.

I'm trying to only allow `3` digit numbers and is only between `0 - 180`.

Also, I'm trying to only allow (in a separate token) 2 digit numbers between `0` and `59.9999` **(4 decimal places).**

I have no idea how to create the regex for these two tokens in JavaCC...

Any help would with an explanation would be awesome thanks :)

Comment: you can generate regexes to match a numeric range using this online tool: http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first case, your pattern needs to allow 1-digit numbers, 2-digit numbers, 3-digit numbers whose first digit is 1 and whose second digit is in the range 0-7, and the special case 180.  The regex would look like

```
[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-7][0-9]|180
```

(I don't know javacc, so I don't know how this regex would be used, or whether you need something else to prevent something like `1800` from being parsed as a number, or as two numbers.  You might need `\b` on the ends to indicate a word boundary, but I have no idea how javacc works.)

For the second case, the part to the left of the decimal point is either one digit, or two digits where the first digit is in the range 0-5.  Your requirements aren't clear, but if the token is required to have a decimal point and one to four digits to the right of the decimal point, the regex would be

```
([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])\.[0-9]{1,4}
```

Again, I don't know how javacc handles the word boundaries.

Note that if this were a Java program, I would recommend (in the first case) just parsing it as an integer and comparing it to 0 and 180.  Too many questioners try to use regexes to solve every problem, but they are not suited for every problem.  Since this is for javacc, it may be a context in which regexes are simple to use and numeric comparisons are not--as I've mentioned, I don't know anything about javacc.

Comment: To make this JavaCC friendly, put double quotes around the strings. E.g., `["0"-"9"]{1,2}|"1"["0"-"7"][0-9]|"180"`.